# How can I refresh a page with the same selection selected? (Jade/HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pug

I am using Jade to create a drop down list on a webpage. I want to have this webpage constantly reload(perhaps by a certain time interval) when an item is selected, but I want it to reload with the same selection still selected.

Using something like meta(http-equiv='refresh', content='30') could work for me, but it only reloads the original page every 30 seconds, but not the page with the selected item in the list already selected.

Here is my code:

```
select(id="foo", multiple="2", size=listStuff.length)
    each val in listStuff
    option(value=val)=val

script.
 $('#foo').on('change', function(context) {

        //insert what the selection displays when changed
   });
```

I know I am using jade, but any html experience is welcome, as I can convert between the two languages.

Comment: You will need to either create a [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or use [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store the selected value and then check for that value on reload.

Comment: or use the query portion of the url...

Comment: the url does not change when you have an item selected in a drop down list, that's why I can't just say refresh this url.

Comment: right, you'd have to modify it by adding `?selection=1` or something, then read it on reload, similar to first comment...

Comment: You could use replacestate api to append a url parameter, else if you use window.location it would cause a page refresh each time select is changed.

Comment: @WhiteHat how would I modify each selection to have different urls?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a replacestate api as @aarjithn mentioned, but to use the url approach, you would need to refresh the page via JavaScript rather than a 'meta' tag. then you could set the url appropriately before triggering the refresh...

Comment: @Nicole Pinto Set this to do in a setInterval function: `window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?selection=" + $("#foo").val();`

Answer (score 0):

So you need to persist the option in select after refresh. You have couple of options, use session/local storage api or set it in a cookie.

using session storage:

```
$('#foo').on('change', function(context) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("foo", $("#foo").val());
});
```

and then on page load

```
$('#foo').val(sessionStorage.getItem("foo"));
```

If on cookie, you would use something like (jQuery cookie)

```
$.cookie("foo",  $("#foo").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example using the Query string from the URL.
I use the `id` of the `select` element as the query string name.

```
window.addEventListener('load', initPage, false);

var elSelect;  // select element

function initPage(sender) {
    var selectionValue;  // selection from url

    // get select, set value, refresh page in 30 seconds
    elSelect = document.getElementById('foo');
    selectionValue = getQueryString(elSelect.id);
    if (selectionValue) {
        elSelect.value = selectionValue;
    }
    setTimeout(refreshPage, 30000);
}

function refreshPage(sender) {
    var newUrl;  // url to load

    // set new query portion, reload
    newUrl = "?" + elSelect.id + "=" + elSelect.value;
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + newUrl;
}

// get query string value by name
function getQueryString(sParm) {
    var asParms;  // query String parameters array

    var sLocation;  // location URL
    var sParmName;  // parameter name
    var sParmVal;   // parameter value

    // return false if not found
    sParmVal = false;

    // split query portion of url, look for sParm name
    sLocation = location.search.substring(1, location.search.length);
    asParms = sLocation.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < asParms.length; i++) {
        sParmName = asParms[i].substring(0,asParms[i].indexOf("="));
        if (sParmName === sParm) {
            sParmVal = asParms[i].substring(asParms[i].indexOf("=") + 1)
        }
    }

    return sParmVal;
}

<select id="foo">
  <option value="1" selected>fe</option>
  <option value="2">fi</option>
  <option value="3">fo</option>
</select>
```